# search for string in line

Tags: java, string, text-files

I have problem dealing with a string in a line,
For example i have the following lines in a .txt file:

```
ussdserver link from host /127.0.0.1:38978(account smpp34) is up|smpp34|2012-10-28 17:02:19
ussdserver link from host localhost/127.0.0.1:8088(account callme) is up|callme|2012-10-28 17:02:20
```

I need my code to get the word after "account" (in the first line it's smpp34) and the word "up" (after the "is" word).

I thought about using `String.charAt()` method but it doesn't work here because the words that I need can be in different places, as shown in the example above.

Comment: What have you tried? have you checked out String indexOf and substring? Do you have any understanding of regular expressions?

Comment: Use Regular Expressions instead of charAt.
java.lang.regex.

Answer (score 1):

Try using following methods form [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class.

```
String inputStr = "ussdserver link from host /127.0.0.1:38978(account smpp34) is up|smpp34|2012-10-28 17:02:19";
int index1 = inputStr.indexOf("account");
int index2 = inputStr.indexOf(')',index1);
String accountName = inputStr.substring(index1+8,index2); // you get smpp34

index1 = inputStr.indexOf("|");
index2 = inputStr.lastIndexOf(' ', index1);
String state = inputStr.substring(index2+1, index1) // you get up
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah its best to use regex in this sort of cases..But a simpler method can be used specifically for **above case**. Simply Try splitting from **)** and then read till length of string-5 to length will give you the first word and try similar for second word..

IF and Only if the String pattern above never changes..Else will recommend using regex..

Answer (score 0):

Try RegEx like this.

> ```
>   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*account\\s([^\\s]*)\\)\\sis\\s([^|]*)|.*");
>   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("ussdserver link from host /127.0.0.1:38978(account smpp34) is up|smpp34|2012-10-28 17:02:19");
>   while (matcher.find()) {
>     System.out.println(matcher.group(1));//will give you 'smpp34'
>     System.out.println(matcher.group(2));//will give you 'up'
>     return;
>   }
> ```